# Angular build watch creating multiple main.js files

Tags: angular

I am running the following command

> npx ng build --watch=true

and it is generating the correct files in the dist folder with the hash. However if I change a file it is generating a new main.xxxxx.js & polyfills.xxxx.js files instead of overwriting the existing main.xxxx.js & polyfills.xxxxx.js file, because of this the new change is not being reflected on the page.

Comment: what is your question?  Are you expecting ng build to reload the browser when files change?

Comment: @cobolstinks I am expecting ng build --watch=true to overwrite the compiled files so that when I refresh the browser it should pick the new changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss understand what `ng build` does.  Its meant to build your app, not serve it in a browser.  If you want to build and serve your app in a browser and get hot reloading in a browser you need to run.

`npx ng serve`

Comment: I am actually building the angular app and exposing it using nodejs which also has the logic for my backend services, that way I can run them on the same port number.